# Jquery .change check for dirty form

Tags: jquery, forms, input, dialog

I have just started working with PHP and JQuery and want to display an alertbox if all input field in a form is dirty - and if not, go to the selected page. I can’t get the code below to function.

```
var formChanged = false;

function check_dirtyForm(){
    $(':input',document.myForm).change(function() {
        formChanged = true;
    });
}

function show_new_page($controller) {
    check_dirtyForm();
    if (formChanged == true)
    {
        alert("Form is dirty");
    }
    else
    {
        //show page
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `show_new_page()` called? Any errors in the console? Can you set up a JS Fiddle to show the problem?

Comment: @Utkanos Thanks for question. It is called from link <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="show_new_page('offer');return false">Offer</a> and I don't know about JS Fiddle. But I can look in to it. Martin

Comment: @Utkanos, I have set up a JS Fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/C9hZm/18/ and it works there - so the error is not in the code above. Thanks for your hint and help. Martin

Comment: If I change the line with a call to another function "//show page" with an alertbox the code works. I think that there is something wrong with de declaration of the var formChanged - but I can’t get it right. Any help is appreciated - thanks. Martin

Comment: As you say, the Fiddle works fine. There is nothing wrong with this code. If you still have a problem, I can only suggest setting up a Fiddle that more accurately reflects your real environment so you can try to reproduce the error there. Unless you can demonstrably reproduce it, it'll be hard for me or anyone to help.

Comment: @Utkanos, Thanks. I try to reproduce and locate the error. Thanks again. Martin

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dirtyFields](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/dirtyFields/examples.cfm) plugin and check for "dirtyForm" class on your Form.